# “Invalid use of aggregating function in this context” using COUNT query (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to display a graph with both nodes displayed to look at only the persons who submitted more than one claim. This only displays the persons nodes.

```
MATCH (p:Persons)-[r:submitted]->(q:Claims)
WITH p,
COUNT(r) AS cnt 
WHERE cnt > 1
RETURN p;
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, Here is the solution.

```
MATCH (p:Persons)-[r:submitted]->(c:Claims) 
WITH p,count(c) as rels, collect(c) as claims
WHERE rels > 1
RETURN p,claims,rels
```

Comment: You can simplify it to:
```
MATCH (p:Persons)-[r:submitted]->(c:Claims) 
WITH p, COLLECT(c) AS claims
WHERE SIZE(claims) > 1
RETURN p,claims
```
no need for an extra COUNT if you already aggregate the claims.